# Highcharts force to 0 before climbing again

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart that I am generating the data for dynamically based on a date range entered by the user.  The data in the table is power readings.  The readings are done every hour.  If there is no power then nothing is reported and saved in the database.  So, I have a chart ([jsfiddle sample/dPqg7/](http://jsfiddle.net/dPqg7/)) that I am using to display the data.  However, the chart is linking the last reading from one day to the first reading of the second day.  Is there any way to force the series to zero before it starts going back up on the next day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.  If you want it to be zero then the [**last reading on the first day must be zero and the first reading on the second day must be zero**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPqg7/4/).  Or since you are dynamically creating the data, you could keep track of the hours and if data is missing automatically set it to [**null**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPqg7/5/) or [**zero**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPqg7/6/).

Me personally, I would like to display data for every data point within the users date range.  So I would display zeros for every hour that data is not present.

I noticed that your tooltip is showing m/s.  I am guessing you used another chart and missed changing it to kwh.

Comment: Thanks for all of the examples.  I never really thought of controlling the hours with no values on the server side.  I agree, I like seeing a value present for every hour, even if it is zero.